# Evaluate the following for a standard normal probability distribution, drawing an appropriate picture.

Tags: statistics

My professor cut off lecture early and did not cover this in class and we will cover this material in the final. She sent us the solution to this problem after class but skipped a lot of steps and I am unsure of how she arrived at the solution.

Evaluate the following for a standard normal probability distribution, drawing an appropriate picture. Find the standard normal z-value so that the area between –z and z is 0.9030.

- She got the Z value to be 1.66 and shaded in the normal distribution area between -1.66 and 1.66.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want the area (i.e. probability) between $0$ and $z$ to be?  Between $-z$ and $0$? Above $z$? Below $z$?  Do you have tables or a calculator that can turn one of these probabilities into a number of standard deviations?

Comment: I have no clue this problem is confusing me beyond any idea. I do have a TI-84 but I don't know how to turn one of these probabilities into a standard deviation.